# How to set two colors in UIButton background

Tags: swift, swift2, uicolor, cgcolor

I want to set two different colors in `UIButton` background. I know how to set one color or border and etc. But I don't know how to set two different colors in the background. I show the example. I use Swift 2

[image]

Comment: You probably need to use an image as background. I highly doubt there is a way to set multiple color side by side like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a gradient with 2 pair of repeating colours:

```
let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = button.bounds
gradient.colors = [
    UIColor.greenColor().CGColor,
    UIColor.greenColor().CGColor,
    UIColor.blackColor().CGColor,
    UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
]

/* repeat the central location to have solid colors */
gradient.locations = [0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0]

/* make it horizontal */
gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5)
gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0.5)

button.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
```

You can change the orientation playing with the start/end points:

```
gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CAGradientLayer` to make it

```
let layer : CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
layer.frame.size = button.frame.size
layer.startPoint = CGPointZero
layer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0)

let colorGreen = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
let colorBlack = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

layer.colors = [colorGreen, colorGreen, colorBlack, colorBlack]
layer.locations = [0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0]

button.layer.insertSublayer(layer, atIndex: 0)
```