# Swift: How to design cell view as two triangles?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How to make cell with two triangles, or two halfs with diagonal line in between.

I currently use solution advised here [How to set two colors in UIButton background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435117/how-to-set-two-colors-in-uibutton-background) but it's not exactly what I need, since I need a little white or transparent space in between, like this: http://i66.tinypic.com/np5dex.png

Comment: You can quite easily modify the code you linked to to use third color to achieve the spacing between these "triangles".

Comment: Create a view with the same background color as the background. set width equal to `pythagoras` for the view, rotate it half a `pi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the gradient solution that you linked too. All you need to do is add more gradient stops, so that there will be a white/transparent section in the middle of the gradient. Play around with something like this

```
gradient.colors = [
    UIColor.orange.cgColor,
    UIColor.orange.cgColor,
    UIColor.clear.cgColor,
    UIColor.clear.cgColor,
    UIColor.green.cgColor,
    UIColor.green.cgColor,
]
gradient.locations = [0, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 1.0]
```